# Cannot find GOROOT directory: /usr/local/go

Tags: go

```
I have put this in / go / src /first_webapp  server.go
```

And when I run the command go install first webapp I get this error,

```
cannot find GOROOT directory: /usr/local/go
```

Comment: You likely have set a `GOROOT` environment variable when you shouldn't have.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you have installed Golang correctly and set your env variables like it says in here: https://golang.org/doc/install